# Combine output of parallel operations using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

The following snippet of code processes the filters in parallel and write out individual files to the output directory.Is there a way to get one large output file?

```
Array(
        (filter1, outputPathBase + fileName),
        (filter2, outputPathBase + fileName),
        (filter3, outputPathBase + fileName)   

      ).par.foreach {
        case (extract, path) => extract.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").csv(path)
      }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the array into a single RDD by union them, that would parallelize the execution of each filter* by Spark

```
val rdd = Array(
        filter1
        filter2,
        filter3).reduce(_.union(_))

rdd.write.mode("append").csv(path)
```

There is no need in this case to convert the `Array` to a `ParArray`

I am assuming that `filter1`, `filter2` and `filter3` are of the same type `RDD[T]`

Comment: Thank you Mikel. I tried that too.However,the difference in total execution time was huge. With the approach I used the processing was done in 3 minutes and with the approach with the union took about 18 minutes.

Comment: can you share more information about what filter1, filter2 and filter3 are?

Comment: I have removed the coalesce(1) that would make the parallelization to be reduced to 1

Comment: All the filters are of the same type.I will try this out.